# How does style elements such as "color" in CSS apply to elements like img?

Tags: html, css

I am currently reading a book on HTML to develop websites and I came across an exercise that required me to highlight the elements in a tree diagram that would be affected by the style rule

`div#intro{color: red;}`

Here is an image of the solution https://i.stack.imgur.com/615Fq.jpg. I don't quite agree with it because I don't think you can give an img element the color red. Is the solution incorrect or is it my understanding of inheritance incorrect?

Comment: The solution shows `div` being assigned a color, not an `img`.

Comment: In the inheritance diagram, there is a leaf node "img".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well any text associated with the image will be red. If I don't provide a `src`, for instance, but provide `alt` text... the `alt` text will be red.

[Look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PXBP/.)

HTML

```
<div id="red">
    <img alt="This is my alternate text" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#red {
    color: #F00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The image tag would still inherit the color, but you are right in vast majority of cases it wouldn't actually do anything. The only instance I can think of that it would be actually visible to the user would be if your image isn't found and it shows the alt text instead of the image. In this case the alt text for the image would be red.

A better example would probably have been background-color, as there are more scenarios where that would be useful. E.g. you could have padding around your image and the background colour would be visible, or if you're using a transparent PNG then the background colour would be visible behind the image when applied to the image tag.